# Equation simplification issue in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify

The following equation (which actually evaluates to zero) is not being simplified to zero by Mathematica. I have tried the commands known to me, like Simplify, FullSimplify, Cancel, etc. The equation is given below in InputForm. The image of the equation from Mathematica is also given below.

```
\[Rho]^3 (Subscript[r, to]/\[Rho])^((
  6 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])/(\[Beta] + 
   2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])) (\[Beta] + 
    2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 
     1])^3 - (\[Rho] (\[Beta] + 2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]))^((
  3 \[Beta])/(\[Beta] + 
   2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])) (Subscript[r, 
    to] (\[Beta] + 2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]))^((
  6 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])/(\[Beta] + 2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]))
```

How do I get Mathematica to evaluate this to zero? [Original Expression Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdqhp.png)

I thought the problem could be with addition and cancellation of exponents. So I tried this simpler expression given below:

```
(\[Beta] + 2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])^((
 3 \[Beta])/(\[Beta] + 
  2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])) (\[Beta] + 2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])^((
 6 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1])/(\[Beta] + 2 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]))
```

This worked fine, as can be see in the image. [Image with Simpler expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxEpy.jpg)

How can we make Mathematica cancel and evaluate the original expression to zero? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a mathematica forum on StackExchange too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently needs some assumptions

```
expr = ρ^3 (Subscript[r, to]/ρ)^((
  6 Subscript[γ, 1])/(β + 
   2 Subscript[γ, 1])) (β + 
    2 Subscript[γ, 1])^3 - (ρ (β + 2 Subscript[γ, 1]))^((3 β)/(β + 
   2 Subscript[γ, 1])) (Subscript[r, to] (β + 2 Subscript[γ, 1]))^((
  6 Subscript[γ, 1])/(β + 2 Subscript[γ, 1]))

FullSimplify[expr, Assumptions ->
  β > 0 && Subscript[γ, 1] > 0 &&
   ρ > 0 && Subscript[r, to] > 0]
```

> 0

```
FullSimplify[expr, Assumptions -> ρ > 0 && Subscript[r, to] > 0]
```

> 0